# What is the difference between 'because of' and 'for'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, difference

I cant tell when i should use them or if they are interchangeable

Examples

> I don't eat meat (for/because of) various reasons

> Scotland is famous (for/because of) its spectacular countryside

Comment: In the examples given either is fine but I would suggest “for” is the better choice for flow and clarity.

Comment: You don't say "Scotland is **famous because of**" the fixed expression is ... **famous for (its castles)** ... Kate Bunting's answer below gets it right.

Comment: Related: [“X is famous” vs. “X was famous”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103846/x-is-famous-vs-x-was-famous)

Comment: also related: [Use of “because of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91344) and [When are “because”, “since”,“for” and “as” interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6993)

Answer (score 2):

They are very different:

- "Because" introduces a *reason* for something
- "For" introduces a *purpose*.

The only reason they are ever interchangeable is that sometimes the reason and the purpose may be the same thing.

For example, if your Doctor told you to eat more fruit because your health was poor, the *reason* for eating fruit is your *poor* health, but the *purpose* of eating it is to gain *good* health. So, you could say *both*:

> - I'm eating more fruit because of my health.
> - I'm eating more fruit for my health.

In different scenarios, this would not be the case. For example, if you were eating in your garden but being attacked by wasps, you might say:

> - I'm taking my food inside *because* of the wasps.

That would mean the wasps are the *reason* you are going inside. You wouldn't say "I'm taking my food inside *for* the wasps" because that would sound like you were going to give your food to the wasps inside.

---

Looking at your examples:

> I don't eat meat for/<s>because of</s> various reasons

This example is a little complex because you are citing 'reasons' but not actually saying what they are. "Because" introduces a reason, so you would use that if you were saying what that reason was (eg "*I don't eat meat because it is unethical*"), but here you should use "*for*" because you do it *in support of* your reasons.

> Scotland is famous (for/because of) its spectacular countryside

In this example, either could work. You could say it is "*famous for* its spectacular countryside" because it is *still* famous. You could also say it is "*famous because of its spectacular countryside*" because it is *historically* famous.

Consider something historically famous that doesn't exist anymore such as the Roman Empire. If you spoke of it in the past tense (eg using "was") you could say "The Roman empire *was famous for* its military might". However, even though it doesn't exist to speak of in the present tense, you could still speak of its *fame* in the present tense, because people still know about it today. In doing so, you couldn't use "for" because there is no future purpose in a dead empire - you would have to say "the Roman Empire **is** remembered *because of* its military might".

Comment: The 2nd example in the OP is the fixed phrase *famous for* There's  no purpose in: "Wasps and bees  are famous for ruining many a  picnic."

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn't use that phrase?

Comment: You didn't mention "famous for" at all in the answer before the edit that was my point.

Comment: @Astralbee I looked in all the dictionaries and it says that 'for' among  its various meanings,one of them is for introducing reason. Also i searched up sentences containing 'is remembered for' it popped up some examples like:"He is remembered for his contributions" . This response confused me even more.

Comment: @Astralbee PS:Talking about my example: he is remembered FOR a 'reason' it couldn't be a 'purpose'.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not generally interchangeable.*For the reason that/for various reasons* and *famous for* are fairly standard expressions. However, you could say

> I don't eat meat because of my objection to killing animals/because I object to...